# Simple Javascript replace with a loop

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm try to replace all occurances wihtin a string with the array index value as below.

```
var str = '<a href="{0}" title="{1}">{1}</a>';
var params= [];
params.push('Url', 'TitleDisplay');

for (i in params) {
    var x = /'{' + i + '}'/g;
    str = str.replace(x, params[i]);
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get it to work. Dropping the '/g' works with one match, but not all. I know this is basic but for the lide of me I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Don't use `for... in... ` for arrays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bdy6G/1/)

Code:

```
var rx = /{([0-9]+)}/g;
str=str.replace(rx,function($0,$1){return params[$1];});
```

The replace method loops through the string (because of /g in the regex) and finds all instances of {n} where n is a number. $1 captures the number and the function replaces {n} with params[n].

Answer (score 2):

try using this:

```
var x = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "g");
```

instead of this:

```
var x = /'{' + i + '}'/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a regexp object if you need it to be dynamic

```
var str = '<a href="{0}" title="{1}">{1}</a>';
var params= [];
params.push('Url', 'TitleDisplay');

for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var x = new RegExp('(\\{'+i+'\\})', 'g');
    str = str.replace(x, params[i]);
}
alert(str);
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LByBT/

Answer (score 1):

How about this if you would like to skip a regex solution ..

```
function replaceAllOccurrences(inputString, oldStr, newStr) 
{
    while (inputString.indexOf(oldStr) >= 0)
    {
        inputString = inputString.replace(oldStr, newStr);
    }

    return inputString;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code and the input strings you use - for me I use this successfully across a variety of projects

Comment: @emotality that is because probably you are replacing a string with the  same string with something in front of or at the end of it