# Regex: are digit matches returned as string or number?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, object-type

Yesterday I was answering a question on stackoverflow, and there's something I don't understand in my own answer...

References: [the thread in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446105/simple-javascript-replace-with-a-loop), and [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdy6G/)

Here is the code from my answer:

```
var rx = /{([0-9]+)}/g;
str=str.replace(rx,function($0,$1){return params[parseInt($1)];});
```

Now, what surprises me is that the following code works too:

```
var rx = /{([0-9]+)}/g;
str=str.replace(rx,function($0,$1){return params[$1];});
```

My question: how come parseInt is not needed? At what point does JavaScript convert $1 into a number? Is it in the regex, or in the array?

Comment: Have you tried using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)?

Comment: doh...no, I should have started there. I just tried and it says string. So it seems that for the array 1 and '1' are the same.

Comment: I think of `Array` as `Object`, but with special treatment to keys that only contains non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because javascript reads indexes as a string

`array[1]`, will be converted to `array['1']` before being read

The same way `object['first']` will work

Comment: So using parseInt sounds rather stupid. I have updated my answer on the other post. Thanks... learning everyday.